# Converting PMF to CDF

Tags: probability

How would I convert the following Probability Mass Function into a CDF?

If the PMF $PX$ of $X$ is given by

$$PX( 1) = 0.4,PX(0) = 0.1,PX(1) = 0.3,PX(3) = 0.2$$

What is the CDF of $X$?

Answer (score 0):

In general $X$ is a discrete random variable iff a countable set $S$ exists with $P(X\in S)=1$.

If $S$ is such a set and $p_s:=P(X=s)$ for every $s\in S$ then:$$F_X(x)=\sum_{s\in S\cap(-\infty,x]}p_s$$

It is handsome to do this for $S:=\{s\in\mathbb R\mid P(X=s)>0\}$.

If $S$ is finite and $S=\{s_0,s_1,\dots,s_n\}$ where $s_0<s_1<\cdots<s_n$ then discern the cases:

- $x<s_0$
- $s_{i-1}\leq x<s_{i}$ for $i=1,\dots, n$
- $s_n\leq x$